# WPF MVVM Dynamic DataTable Binding does not show value of cells

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, grid

I have a DataGrid that shows Data from a DataTable which is bound into my code-behind.
(The TableData I want to draw is depending on the selectedItem of a ComboBox. It changes the column headers when changing the selectedItem, so i think this is not a problem. See this in the two prictures below)

So, the DataGrid in .xaml looks like this:

```
  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentTable.CurrentDataTable.DefaultView}" >
  </DataGrid>
```

In my ViewModel I have an object named "CurrentTable" from the class TableInformation.
It looks like this:

```
public class TableInformation : BaseViewModel
  {
    public string TableName; //with geter, seter
    public DataTable CurrentDataTable; //with geter, seter
  }
```

with inheritates from BaseViewModel because of the PropertyChanged Event (this works fine!).

When loading my CurrentTable, the code looks like this:

```
public void LoadInitialJsonData()
    {
      // Fill all table data
      QtyTopLevelKeys = BPPCjson_if.BPPCjson_getTableCount(context);
      for (int curTableIdx = 0; curTableIdx < QtyTopLevelKeys; curTableIdx++)
      {
        int    qtyRows      = // rowCount
        int    qtyCols      = // columnCount
        var    curDataTable = new DataTable();

        // set Header Name for each column
        for (int curCol = 0; curCol < qtyCols; curCol++)
        {
          string curHeader = //unique headername from interface
          if (!curDataTable.Columns.Contains(curHeader)) 
          { 
            curDataTable.Columns.Add(curHeader, typeof(string));
            // PropertyChangedEvent has no effect here
          }
        }

        // set Value for each cell
        for (int curRow = 0; curRow < qtyRows; curRow++)
        {
          DataRow curRowData;
          curRowData = curDataTable.NewRow();
          for (int curCol = 0; curCol < qtyCols; curCol++)
          {
            string data = //value of cell
            curRowData[curCol] = data;
          }
          curDataTable.Rows.Add(curRowData);
        }
        curDataTable.TableName = //unique Name
        TableInformation ti = new TableInformation(curTableName, qtyRows, qtyCols, curDataTable);
        AllTables.Add(ti);
      }
    }
```

Unfortunately, the shown Table looks like this:

[Cell-values not shown but cells are existing 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0aB4.png)

[Cell-values not shown but cells are existing 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XehaJ.png)

Can you help me? Why does it show the correct amount of Rows/Cells but without any content?

It also says that I have binding errors. But i do not really understand why...
[Binding errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY6UA.png)

Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: "do not really understand why" - because your "unique headernames" are incompatible with binding path syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by myself and with a little help of @ASh.

My "unique headernames" did contain dots.

All I did was replacing googling what could help.

This helped me: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7d84c8f2-2709-4642-a259-739036ffd2a6/having-a-dot-in-column-name-will-cause-datagrid-cells-to-be-empty?forum=wpf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).